# R: Working with sparse matrices within snow clusters

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, snow

I am trying to work with sparse matrices generated by igraph under a parallel cluster made by snow, but it seems that operations such as taking a sum of the matrix or doing something like which(element > 0) don't work even though their non-parallel versions do.  Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
library(igraph)
library(snow)

set.seed(123)
random_graph <- as_adjacency_matrix(erdos.renyi.game(100,0.1))

n_edges <- function(random_graph){
  return(sum(random_graph))
}

n_parallel <- 4
cl <- makeCluster(n_parallel)
clusterExport(cl,ls(),environment())

foo <- parSapply(cl,1:10,function(n){
      return(n_edges(random_graph))
})
```

If I run this, it returns the following error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: invalid 'type' (S4) of argument
```

However, this works:

```
> n_edges(random_graph)
[1] 948
```

Since I've exported everything to the cluster it's very odd that it would treat the data structure differently somehow.  What am I missing?